# MySQL Query Error - Insert

Tags: mysql

Not sure why its returning this error, I can't find the bug!

Can somebody please help me?

Code:

```
$user = user($_SESSION["uid"],"*");
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    if(!empty($_POST["message"])){
        if(!empty($_POST["title"])){
            $title = $_POST['title'];
            $message = $_POST['message'];
            $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tickets` (`id`, `username`, `title`, `message`, `date`) VALUES (NULL, '$user', '$title', '$message', NOW()");
            if (!$result) {
                die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
            } else {
                echo "<p class='box green'>Successfully created ticket.</p>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "<p class='box red'>You left the title field blank!</p>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<p class='box red'>You left the message field blank!</p>";
    }
```

Error:

```
Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

Comment: You're missing the closing `)` on the `VALUES ()` clause.

Comment: When MySQL reports `syntax to use near ''` with an empty string at the end, it usually means the very last character of the query is faulty.

Comment: Oh god thats embarrassing on my part. Thankyou so much!

Comment: please read the Warning red box in : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to close your parentheses at the end of your query.

This line:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tickets` (`id`, `username`, `title`, `message`, `date`) VALUES (NULL, '$user', '$title', '$message', NOW()");
```

Should be:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tickets` (`id`, `username`, `title`, `message`, `date`) VALUES (NULL, '$user', '$title', '$message', NOW())");
```